# Receiving ValueError: x and y must be the same size for x and y values. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Currently working a machine learning problem for predicting the weather. Here however I while I was running my code in Jupyter notebook I came across the above error and I am not sure where I am going wrong as the values for my data should both be in 2d arrays. Any help would be greatly appreciated. In my notebook it specifically mentions line 133

```
        axes[row, col]. scatter(df2[feature], df2['meantempm'])
```

as the problem. If it helps I am using https://stackabuse.com/using-machine-learning-to-predict-the-weather-part-2/ as my pain resource for this

```
import jupyter
import IPython
from IPython import get_ipython
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, median_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score, \
    mean_absolute_error, \
    median_absolute_error
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('end-part2_df.csv').set_index('date')

df.corr()[['meantempm']].sort_values('meantempm')

predictors = ['meantempm_1',  'meantempm_2',  'meantempm_3',
              'mintempm_1',   'mintempm_2',   'mintempm_2',
              'meandewptm_1', 'meandewptm_2', 'meandewptm_3',
              'maxdewptm_1',  'maxdewptm_2',  'maxdewptm_3',
              'mindewptm_1',  'mindewptm_2',  'mindewptm_3',
              'maxtempm_1',   'maxtempm_2',   'maxtempm_3']

df2 = df[['meantempm'] + predictors]

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib','inline')

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 22]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=3, sharey=True)

arr = np.array(predictors).reshape(6, 3)

for row, col_arr in enumerate(arr):
    for col, feature in enumerate(col_arr):
        axes[row, col]. scatter(df2[feature], df2['meantempm'])
        if col == 0:
            axes[row, col].set(xlabel=feature, ylabel='meantempm')
        else:
            axes[row, col].set(xlabel=feature)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Solved it, I accidentally put in mintempm_2, again instead of mintempm_3

Answer (score 0):

Your df['mintempm_2'] is 2D (997, 2). This is because in your *predictors* array you have included 'mintempm_2' twice.